# li inside ul are not evenly spaced

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image: enter image description here[1]]

So on desktop media query breakpoint the `li` inside `.dropdown-content` is supposed to be evenly spaced by `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` but the last `li` is really close to the second last `li` and I can't figure out why.

A lot of people are saying it works for them but I don't understand how it does? Go here --> https://teambrainstorm.dev/

I could use margin but I want to know if there's another solution around it using `css-grid`. Also not part of the problem but if anyone knows how to do make the desktop media query breakpoint work simply with just `css-grid` and not using breakpoints let me know.

Trying to make my website without any breakpoints.

Code in [link](https://jsfiddle.net/lambsbaaacode/zvonkgLx/)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
header {
    grid-template-areas: "logo dp gin";
    #switch {
        display: none;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        display: grid;
        position: relative;
        grid-template-rows: none;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        background-color: #fff;
        li {
            padding: 0;
            a {
                color: #212121;
                &:hover {
                    color: #03A9F4;
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

complete **snippet** from JsFiddle:

```js
$("#switch").click(function() {
  $(".fa-bars").toggle();
  $(".fa-times").toggle();
  event.preventDefault();
});

$("#arrow-1").click(function() {
  $(".fa-angle-down").toggle();
  $(".fa-angle-up").toggle();
});

$("#arrow-2").click(function() {
  $(".fa-angle-down").toggle();
  $(".fa-angle-up").toggle();
});

$("#arrow-3").click(function() {
  $(".fa-angle-down").toggle();
  $(".fa-angle-up").toggle();
});

function myFunction(){}

// The debounce function receives our function as a parameter
const debounce = (fn) => {

  // This holds the requestAnimationFrame reference, so we can cancel it if we wish
  let frame;

  // The debounce function returns a new function that can receive a variable number of arguments
  return (...params) => {

    // If the frame variable has been defined, clear it now, and queue for next frame
    if (frame) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
    }

    // Queue our function call for the next frame
    frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {

      // Call our function and pass any params we received
      fn(...params);
    });

  }
};


// Reads out the scroll position and stores it in the data attribute
// so we can use it in our stylesheets
const storeScroll = () => {
  document.documentElement.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
}

// Listen for new scroll events, here we debounce our `storeScroll` function
document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), {
  passive: true
});

// Update scroll position for first time
storeScroll();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
}
 body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #212121;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 textarea, select, input, button {
  outline: none;
}
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
 h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
 h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
 h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
 p, a, button, li, input {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
 button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
 input, button {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
 input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #212121;
}
 input:hover, input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
 a, button, input {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
 a:hover, button:hover, input:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
 a {
  color: #212121;
}
 a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}
 input::placeholder {
  color: #212121;
}
 .site {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 300px 200px 200px 200px 200px 200px 500px;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "title" "qaz" "qaz" "qaz" "qaz" "qaz" "end";
}
 html:not([data-scroll='0']) header {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 50, 100, 0.5);
}
 header {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-area: header;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "dp logo gin";
}
 .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: dp;
}
 .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  grid-area: dc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 2px solid #1565c0;
  background-color: #1565c0;
}
 .dropdown-content li {
  padding: 12px 10px;
}
 .dropdown-content li a {
  color: #81d4fa;
}
 .dropdown-content li a:hover {
  color: #ffccbc;
}
 .gin, #logo, .dropdown {
  margin: auto;
}
 .set {
  color: #03a9f4;
}
 #switch {
  color: #212121;
  grid-area: switch;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
 #switch:focus {
  outline: none;
}
 .fa-bars, .fa-times {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
 .fa-times {
  display: none;
}
 #logo {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: logo;
}
/*other*/
 .qaz {
  grid-area: qaz;
  background: #42a5f5;
}
 .login {
  display: none;
}
 .signup {
  color: #03a9f4;
}
 .title {
  grid-area: title;
  text-align: center;
  background: #42a5f5;
}
 .title h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
}
 .end {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: end;
  background: #263238;
  grid-template-areas: "end-items";
}
 .end-items {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: end-items;
  grid-template-rows: 62.77px 62.77px 62.77px 124.59px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "brainstorm" "support" "company" "subscribe" "media";
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
}
 .media {
  grid-area: media;
}
 .media h3 {
  color: #7986cb;
}
 #folcon a {
  line-height: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
}
 .social, .api, .num, .email {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
 .social {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
 .api {
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
}
 .log, .sign, .gmail, .micro {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
}
 #instagram {
  color: #e1306c;
}
 .fa-instagram, .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook, .nav-list li a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
 .fa-stack {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
 i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
 .fa-square {
  margin-left: -8px;
}
 .end-items h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #607d8b;
}
 .end-items ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
 .brainstorm {
  grid-area: brainstorm;
}
 .brainstorm h3 {
  color: #4fc3f7;
}
 .end-items li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
 .end-items a {
  color: #fff;
}
 .fa-angle-up, .end-list {
  display: none;
}
 .fa-angle-down, .fa-angle-up {
  float: right;
}
 .support {
  grid-area: support;
}
 .support h3 {
  color: #ff8a65;
}
 .company {
  grid-area: company;
}
 .company h3 {
  color: #4db6ac;
}
 #sub input {
  padding: 0.8rem;
  width: 180px;
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
 .subscribe {
  grid-area: subscribe;
}
 .subscribe h3 {
  color: #f06292;
}
 #sub button {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: -4px;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fa709a 0%, #fee140 100%);
}
 #facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
 #twitter {
  color: #1da1f2;
}
/* If the content is smaller than the minimum width, the minimum width will be applied. If the content is larger than the minimum width, the min-width property has no effect. If the content is larger than the maximum width, it will automatically change the height of the element. If the content is smaller than the maximum width, the max-width property has no effect. 
/* ##Device = Desktops ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops */
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  header {
   grid-template-areas: "logo dp gin";
 }
  header #switch {
   display: none;
 }
  header .dropdown-content {
   display: grid;
   position: relative;
   grid-template-rows: none;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li {
   padding: 0;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li a {
   color: #212121;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li a:hover {
   color: #03a9f4;
 }
}
/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  header {
   grid-template-areas: "logo dp gin";
 }
  header #switch {
   display: none;
 }
  header .dropdown-content {
   display: grid;
   position: relative;
   grid-template-rows: none;
   border: none;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li {
   padding: 0;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li a {
   color: #212121;
 }
  header .dropdown-content li a:hover {
   color: #03a9f4;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel|Gugi|Lato|Montserrat|Open+Sans|Pacifico|Varela+Round|Arvo|Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Cabin|Concert+One|Copse|Cutive|IBM+Plex+Mono|Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Quattrocento|Quattrocento+Sans|Quicksand|Roboto|Roboto+Slab|Sanchez|Work+Sans"
  rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/062ee3baff.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">


<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div class="site">
    <header>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <span id="switch">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </span>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a class="set" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="ideas.html">Ideas</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="res.html">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p id="logo">Brainstorm logo</p>
      <ul class="gin">
        <li><a class="signup" href="signup.html">Free Trial</a></li>
        <li><a class="login" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Brainstorm</h1>
      <p>Create, share, and collaborate ideas.</p>
      <p>All beings develep, brainstorm, and work better together as a team.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="qaz">

    </div>
    <div class="qaz">

    </div>
    <div class="qaz">

    </div>
    <div class="qaz">

    </div>
    <div class="qaz">

    </div>
    <div class="end">
      <div class="end-items">
        <div class="brainstorm">
          <h3>brainstorm<span id="arrow-1"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></h3>
          <ul id="bsm" class="end-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download Brainstorm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extensions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beta</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Developer</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="support">
          <h3>support<span id="arrow-2"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></h3>
          <ul class="end-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="company">
          <h3>company<span id="arrow-3"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span></h3>
          <ul class="end-list">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="subscribe">
          <h3>Subscribe to our newletter</h3>
          <form id="sub" name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify="false">
            <input class="nsl" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <button type="submit" name="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="media">
          <h3>follow us</h3>
          <span id="folcon">
              <a href="#"><button id="instagram" class="social" type="follow" name="instagram"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-3x"></i></span></button>
          </a>
          <a href="#"><button id="twitter" class="social" type="follow" name="twitter"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-3x"></i></span></button></a>
          <a href="#"><button id="facebook" class="social" type="follow" name="facebook"><span class="fa-stack fa-2x"><i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-3x"></i></span></button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="test.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure your browser is up to date and that no extensions are interfering.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't reproduce"?

Comment: @lambsbaaacode it means that it works fine for us

Comment: Hi! Can't reproduce means we can't produce the same error you're describing. It's a common phrase so you might see it a lot.

Comment: thank you but I really don't know how it works for you... https://teambrainstorm.dev/

Comment: @lambsbaaacode It seems we misunderstood what you meant due to some miscommunication. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that your `li`s are spaced differently. All of them are the same distance away from each other and they're all the same exact width. What you're seeing is the result of that: shorter words have more extra space inside of their own `li` than the longer ones, resulting in a greater amount of whitespace to the right of shorter words and a smaller amount of whitespace to the right of longer words.

For example, take a look at the following:

```
// Width of one li.
|||||||||||

// Width of each li.
Home|||||||
About||||||
Ideas||||||
Projects|||
Resources||

// Width of all li when inline.
Home|||||||About||||||Ideas||||||Projects|||Resources||
Home       About      Ideas      Projects   Resources
```

This visualization should show you the exact problem you're encountering. What you want to do isn't having all `li` the same width--what you want is to have all `li` the same distance apart. These are two very different things.

If you want to achieve the result of having even spacing, then don't use a grid display, otherwise the columns will remain the same size and will result in the additional whitespace. Instead, consider using something like an `inline-block` display and setting a `margin` or `padding` value.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to add 3 &nbsp in front of <li><a href="res.html">&nbsp&nbsp&nbspResources</a></li>